# How to prevent an animated icon from bleeding out from within an input box

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-core, animation, css-animations

I have an input field with a search Icon inside. When the user clicks inside the input field the Icon fades out to the left, in doing so, it bleeds out of the input box.

Is there a way to prevent the search Icon from bleeding out? I don't want the Icon to be visible past the border of the input box.

**cshtml page:**

```
<header>
   <nav id="navBar" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
      <div class="search-bar center">
         <img  id="searchIcon" src="https://svgur.com/i/XUB.svg" class="icon search-icon" />
         <input id="searchBox" class="input-text" placeholder="Find games for sale" type="text">
      </div>
   </nav>
</header>
```

**js:**

```
$('#searchBox').on({
    focus: function () {
        document.getElementById("searchIcon").classList.remove("fadeRightSearchIcon");
        document.getElementById("searchIcon").classList.add("fadeLeftSearchIcon");
    },

    blur: function () {
        document.getElementById("searchIcon").classList.remove("fadeLeftSearchIcon");
        document.getElementById("searchIcon").classList.add("fadeRightSearchIcon");

    }
});
```

**css:**

```
.search-bar {
    position: relative;
}

    .search-bar.active .input-text {
        max-width: 80%;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background: #eee;
    }

    .icon {
        position: absolute;
        top: -2px;
        left: 0;
        padding: 13px 15px 13px 11px;
    }

        .search-icon {
            width: 50px;
            height: auto;
        }

.search-bar .input-text {
    height: 45px;
    padding: 8px 6px 8px 40px;
    max-width: 200%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    outline: none !important;
    border: 2px solid;
    width: 550px;
    transition-property: padding;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.input-text:active, .input-text:focus {
    padding: 8px 6px 8px 15px;
}

.fadeLeftSearchIcon {
    animation-name: fadeInLeft;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.fadeRightSearchIcon {
    animation-name: fadeInRight;
        animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}

    @keyframes fadeInLeft {
        0% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

        100% {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateX(-25px);
        }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeft {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-25px);
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-25px);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-25px);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}


.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change to -25% ,check official [site](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes):

```
@keyframes fadeInLeft {
0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-25%);
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeft {
0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-25%);
}
}
```

Result:

[image]